# Author's name in header not displaying

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, author

In this MWE I'm not getting the author's name in the header..

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{bmpsize}
\usepackage[classicReIm]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titling}

\setlength\headheight{20pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textit{\thepage}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textit{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}

% Custom command to set running head for odd and even pages
\newcommand{\oddhead}{\markright{Running Head}}

\begin{document}
    
    \title{Relative Advantage of Latex}
    \date{}
    \author{Rui de S. Cxx\thanks{Polytechnic of Porto: \texttt{rdc@xxx.pt}}}
    
    \maketitle
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    
    \fancyhead[RE]{R.Camps} % Move this line after \author command
    
    \begin{small}
        \textbf{Abstract}
        \\  
        \noindent bla bla.
    \end{small}
    
    \newpage
    
    \section{Introduction}
    
    \textbf{1st paragraph}\\
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \textbf{2nd paragraph}\\
    \lipsum[2]
    \lipsum[2]
    \lipsum[3]
    \lipsum[3]
    
    \newpage
    \lipsum[5]
    \lipsum[6]
    \lipsum[7]
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your document is single-sided, because this is the default of class `article`. So you never have left pages. All pages are right pages, which are called *odd* pages in LaTeX. So your

```
\fancyhead[LE]{R.Camps} % Move this line after \author command
```

that defines a (left aligned) page head element for *even* pages only, cannot result in any output. Either replace it by something like

```
\fancyhead[CO]{R.Camps} % Move this line after \author command
```

which would show the author centered at the page header of *odd* (and therefore all) pages

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% Not needed any longer from LaTeX 2018/10/04.

%\usepackage{amssymb}% Not needed so show the problem or solution.
%\usepackage{amsmath}% Not needed so show the problem or solution.
%\usepackage{txfonts}% Not needed so show the problem or solution.
%\usepackage{mathdots}% Not needed so show the problem or solution.
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{bmpsize}% Not needed so show the problem or solution.
%\usepackage[classicReIm]{kpfonts}% Not needed so show the problem or solution.
%\usepackage{scrextend}% Not needed so show the problem or solution.
%\usepackage{graphicx}% Not needed so show the problem or solution.
%\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}% Not needed so show the problem or solution.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{hyperref}% Not needed so show the problem or solution.
%\usepackage{titling}% Not needed so show the problem or solution.

%\setlength\headheight{20pt}% Not needed so show the problem or solution.

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textit{\thepage}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textit{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}

% Custom command to set running head for odd and even pages
%\newcommand{\oddhead}{\markright{Running Head}}% Not needed so show the problem or solution.

\begin{document}
    
    \title{Relative Advantage of Latex}
    \date{}
    \author{Rui de S. Cxx\thanks{Polytechnic of Porto: \texttt{rdc@xxx.pt}}}
    
    \maketitle
    \thispagestyle{empty}

    \fancyhead[CO]{R.Camps} % Move this line after \author command
    
    \begin{small}
        \textbf{Abstract}
        \\  
        \noindent bla bla.
    \end{small}
    
    \newpage
    
    \section{Introduction}
    
    \textbf{1st paragraph}\\
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \textbf{2nd paragraph}\\
    \lipsum[2]
    \lipsum[2]
    \lipsum[3]
    \lipsum[3]
    
    \newpage
    \lipsum[5]
    \lipsum[6]
    \lipsum[7]
    
\end{document}
```

[image: Page 2 with author in middle of head]

[image: Page 3 with author in middle of head]

or replace

```
\documentclass{article}
```

by

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
```

to have a double-sided document with the author on left (= *even*) pages:

```latex
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
% All preamble code not related to the problem removed
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textit{\thepage}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textit{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}
    
    \title{Relative Advantage of Latex}
    \date{}
    \author{Rui de S. Cxx\thanks{Polytechnic of Porto: \texttt{rdc@xxx.pt}}}
    
    \maketitle
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    
    \fancyhead[RE]{R.Camps} % Move this line after \author command
    
    \begin{small}
        \textbf{Abstract}
        \\  
        \noindent bla bla.
    \end{small}
    
    \newpage
    
    \section{Introduction}
    
    \textbf{1st paragraph}\\
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \textbf{2nd paragraph}\\
    \lipsum[2]
    \lipsum[2]
    \lipsum[3]
    \lipsum[3]
    
    \newpage
    \lipsum[5]
    \lipsum[6]
    \lipsum[7]
    
\end{document}
```

[image: Page 2 with author on the right side of the head]

[image: Page 3 without author]